# Moving UIButton on Y Axis

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, position

I have a few UIButtons in my project, however I'd like to be able to move their position on the Y axis through code. And also, would moving the button trough code affect the auto layout / universal storyboard placement?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using autolayout, remove the constraints before applying a new frame to the button:

```
[button removeConstraints:button.constraints];
[button setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
button.frame = CGRectMake(button.frame.origin.x, button.frame.origin.y + deltaY, button.frame.size.width, button.frame.size.height);
```

Comment: He doesn't have to remove the old constraint, he just can update the existing one.

Comment: I placed this code in an IBActon I have, and when the button is pressed it actually does move the button, however it's moved back to it's original position within a second. Would it be possible to have it stay at it's new position?

Comment: Do you have other constraints in your view?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `AutoLayout` you can use something like this:

```
-(void)setConstraintsYPosition:(CGFloat)yPosition forButton:(UIButton*)button withConstraint:(NSLayoutConstraint*)constraint
{
    constraint.constant = yPosition;
    [self.view needsUpdateConstraints];
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    [button setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

and don't forget to create an IBOutlet for the constraint you want to change/pass